# Scraping table of data from webpage with inconsistently nested html tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to scrape some data off of the tables in https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/footer/data-and-reporting/network-performance/daily-performance/
Specifically, I want to scrape the 'Metropolitan tram' table. However, the html elements aren't structured well and I am unsure how to identify the table by name and scrape the content.

This is what I have tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/footer/data-and-reporting/network-performance/daily-performance/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


tables = soup.find_all("div", class_="mceTmpl table__wrapper")
for table in tables:
    print("NEXT-------------------------------------------")
    print(table, end="\n"*2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May use [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) in case of scraping tables, what is best practice and uses `BeautifulSoup` under the hood and select your table from list by index.

Alternative use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) :

```
soup.select('h3:has(a[name="metrotram"]) + div > div:first-of-type tr')
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pd.read_html(
    requests.get(
        'https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/footer/data-and-reporting/network-performance/daily-performance/', 
        headers={'user-agent':'some agent'}
    ).text,
    header=0
)[1]
```

##### Output

|  | Unnamed: 0 | % timetable delivered | % services on-time at timing points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Sunday, 5 February 2023 | 99.4% | 83.3% |
| 1 | Saturday, 4 February 2023 | 99.4% | 81.8% |
| 2 | Friday, 3 February 2023 | 98.4% | 79.7% |
| 3 | Thursday, 2 February 2023 | 97.9% | 72.8% |
| 4 | Wednesday, 1 February 2023 | 98.9% | 79.1% |
| 5 | Tuesday, 31 January 2023 | 99.0% | 81.4% |
| 6 | Monday, 30 January 2023 | 99.3% | 90.2% |